# Elmah errorMail not working on production

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, email, gmail, elmah

I am using ELMAH in my MVC3 application and logging the errors to a SQL Database and sending emails.

Locally everything is working fine, and emails are being delivered (using casini). But on the production server (IIS7) no emails are being delivered. I am able however to send emails through code!

```
  <elmah>
  <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Elmah.Sql" applicationName="qatar" />
  <errorMail from="errors@gmail.com"
    to="someone@gmail.com"
    subject="Error"
    async="true"
    smtpPort="587"
    smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com"
    enablessl ="true"
    userName="myuser@gmail.com"
    password="mypassword" />
```

Any clues or direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason, but still can't understand why it works locally:

enablessl should be changed to **useSsl**